# How to remove the unwanted empty xmlns in xml output from xslt

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I am trying to build a Soap request. The desired output is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"   
xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders">
<soap:Header>
    <soap1:locale>en</soap1:locale>
    <soap1:authentication>
        <soap1:username>john.doe</soap1:username>
        <soap1:password>psw</soap1:password>
    </soap1:authentication>
</soap:Header>
```

Here is my testing xsl (lanuage, username and password will be passed in real application):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="language" select="'en'"/>
<xsl:param name="username" select="'john.doe'"/>
<xsl:param name="password" select="'psw'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
        xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders" >
        <xsl:call-template name="soapHeader"/>              
        <xsl:call-template name="soapBody"/>
    </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="soapHeader">
    <soap:Header> 
        <soap1:locale><xsl:value-of select="$language" /></soap1:locale>
        <soap1:authentication>
            <soap1:username><xsl:value-of select="$username" /></soap1:username>
            <soap1:password><xsl:value-of select="$password" /></soap1:password>
        </soap1:authentication>
    </soap:Header> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="soapBody">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the output is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders">
<soap:Header xmlns:soap="">
    <soap1:locale xmlns:soap1="">en</soap1:locale>
    <soap1:authentication xmlns:soap1="">
        <soap1:username>john.doe</soap1:username>
        <soap1:password>psw</soap1:password>
    </soap1:authentication>
</soap:Header>
```

There are unwanted empty namespaces, such as xmlns:soap="", xmlns:soap1="".  Can you point me to right directions to eliminate these unwanted artifacts?

Thanks.

Comment: User2254613, I strongly recommend to use a design pattern that allows the presentation to be completely separated from logic -- aka "Fill in the Blanks" technique.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised your XSLT processor accepts that XSLT, as it's not valid XML, but to make it valid and to also (I believe) solve your problem, you should declare the namespaces on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element instead of on the `<soap:Envelope>` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0"
                xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders">
```

Comment: JLRishe, Thank you for help. I tested it with  Altova XMLSpy which did not complain about the xslt. Moving all the namsespaces to where you suggested does do the trick!  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**I strongly recommend to separate the presentation from the logic. In fact, you can have a transformation that is independent of any possible presentation**.

Here comes the "Fill-in-the-blanks" technique (note that it also solves your problem of unwanted namespaces):

**Source XML document**:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders" xmlns:gen="my:gen">
    <soap:Header>
        <soap1:locale><gen:language/></soap1:locale>
        <soap1:authentication>
            <soap1:username><gen:username/></soap1:username>
            <soap1:password><gen:password/></soap1:password>
        </soap1:authentication>
    </soap:Header>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Presentation-independent transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:gen="my:gen">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="language" select="'en'"/>
    <xsl:param name="username" select="'john.doe'"/>
    <xsl:param name="password" select="'psw'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="gen:*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name=local-name(current())]/@select"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders" xmlns:gen="my:gen">
   <soap:Header>
      <soap1:locale>'en'</soap1:locale>
      <soap1:authentication>
         <soap1:username>'john.doe'</soap1:username>
         <soap1:password>'psw'</soap1:password>
      </soap1:authentication>
   </soap:Header>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**You can have now as many different presentation layouts as necessary, and the same transformation without any change (provided all required parameters have been specified) produces any of these formats**.

**For example, if you want to produce the result in this new format:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders">
   <soap:Header>
      <soap1:personalized>
         <soap1:locale>
            <soap1:language>'en'</soap1:language>
         </soap1:locale>
         <soap1:authentication>
            <soap1:username>'john.doe'</soap1:username>
            <soap1:password>'psw'</soap1:password>
         </soap1:authentication>
      </soap1:personalized>
   </soap:Header>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**just apply the same transformation on the following XML document:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:soap1="http://acme.com/ws/soapheaders" xmlns:gen="my:gen">
    <soap:Header>
      <soap1:personalized>
        <soap1:locale>
          <soap1:language><gen:language/></soap1:language>
    </soap1:locale>
        <soap1:authentication>
            <soap1:username><gen:username/></soap1:username>
            <soap1:password><gen:password/></soap1:password>
        </soap1:authentication>
        </soap1:personalized>
    </soap:Header>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Further generalization can be achieved by providing the URL of the layout-document and the url of the Parameters document -- as parameters to the transformation.

Comment: I'm not the person who downvoted this, but your output has apostrophes around the values and this will not work if the parameter values are passed in from externally (which the asker has said he will eventually do).

Comment: @JLRishe, As I pointed at the end of my answer, this is just a demo. Full and general application of this technique will accept both the layout and the parameters as external XML document URIs.